# What visa should I apply for as an Au Pair?

Tags: visas, europe, schengen, italy, work

On June 20 I am backpacking around Europe for almost 3 months with friends and then I will be living in Italy for 3 months as an Au Pair. I am unsure what visa I will need to apply for.

Will I need a study visa (I can sign up for italian classes)?

A subordinate visa? 
And am I able to have a Schengen visa and another visa purely for Italy?

Comment: What nationality are you?

Answer (score 3):

This highly depends what nationality you are. If I assume that you are not from the EU, you need to apply for a long stay visa. If you are non-EU and from Canada, Australia or New Zealand, you can apply for a working holiday visa.

There are two websites which give you more information on the process:

- [aupair-world-agency](http://www.aupair-world-agency.com/useful-information/aupair-visas/aupair-visa-italy.html)
- [aupair-world](http://www.aupair-world.net/index.php/au_pair_program/italy/family/regulations/non_eu/)